# LC Progress Indicator Base not completely colored in till current step

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-progressindicator

I'm using a Lightning:progressIndicator with type 'Base' in a Lightning Component. The problem that I'm having is that when I have a lot of progressSteps, the bar itself is not completely filled in until the current step (see image below). Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

[image: Progress Bar]

```
<lightning:progressIndicator type="base" variant="base" currentStep="{!v.currentStep}">
  <aura:iteration items="{! v.choices }" var="step">
    <lightning:progressStep label="{! step}" value="{! step}" onclick="{!c.onClickStep}" name="{!step}" />
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:progressIndicator>
```

Comment: Can you add the minimal required code to look into your issue?

Comment: Can you also add the code where you are assigning the value to choices and currentStep?

Comment: Why is this relevant to the problem?

Answer (score 4):

The main problem appears to be that the completed items are a different size than the incomplete items:

[image: Completed Container]

[image: Incomplete Container]

These extra 6 pixels make the calculation for the progress bar that is hiding out in the background go slightly awry.

The progress bar involved is compiled, at least in the lightning-base-components library, as:

```
<lightning-progress-bar value={privateProgressValue} size="small"></lightning-progress-bar>
```

With the value being calculated as:

```
if (this.isBase) {
    this.privateProgressValue = computeProgressValue(
        steps,
        currentStepIndex
    );
}
```

...

```
export function computeProgressValue(steps, activeStepIndex) {
    const stepLength = steps.length;
    if (stepLength === 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    return Math.floor((100 / (stepLength - 1)) * activeStepIndex);
}
```

This calculation works if, and only if, the completed and incomplete items are the same size. With only a few steps, it's not noticeable, but the more steps you add, the worse the effect.

[image: Five Options]

[image: Twenty-Five Options]

Unfortunately, the only real solution we can implement as customers/subscribers/external developers is to copy lightning-progress-indicator from lightning-base-components or another source, then fixing the CSS to force the correct size.

This would fix the problem, but each developer would have to implement this.

Here's a [quick demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/EEAtlkYWy64su1SG4D5C/package.json?p=stories) of the problem.

The "fix" at the time of this answer would be to copy the relevant open-source components (see [npm lightning-base-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components)), which would be, at minimum, `lightning-progress-indicator` and `lightning-progress-step`, copying the relevant utility components and/or replacing them with standard components (e.g. `lightning-primitive-icon` can use `lightning-icon` if you're in Salesforce), and fixing the step component to have a consistent size.

The problem, as I see it, is this part of lightning/progressStep/base.html:

```
<template if:true={hasIcon}>
    <lightning-primitive-icon
            icon-name={baseIconName}
            svg-class="slds-button__icon"
            variant="bare"></lightning-primitive-icon>
</template>
```

Because the icon isn't always rendered, the extra space the icon takes up shrinks. If I were going to fix this, I'd use some custom CSS to shrink the icon, or provide a small placeholder alternative to stretch the empty space to use the same size.

Aside from that, the alternative is to restrict the number of options to about six items, which is apparently the maximum number of items that won't expose the bug.

I will try and get in touch with someone at Salesforce regarding this. It seems it should be a simple fix, but it may take some time to get this fixed.

Comment: Very nice explanation!